# Add custom ORM mapping without configuration

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've created a bundle that's being installed using composer, with entities in this folder structure:

```
Components\Product\Entity\Product.php
Components\Category\Entity\Category.php
...
```

So when installing the bundle, I'd have edit my application's configuration file in order to add the correct mapping, for example like this:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        mappings:
            type: annotation
            dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/my-custom/bundle/Components/Product/Entity"
            prefix: 'My\Custom\Bundle'
            alias: MyCustomBundle
```

And this for every folder.

So when installing the bundle, there's a lot of extra configuration in order to add mappings for all of these entities.

Is it possible to define these mappings from within the bundle? Preferably by using a listener or something?

What I'm actually try to achieve is that entities can be defined in the application like this:

```
my_bundle:
    entities: 
        product_entity: App\Entity\Product
        category_entity: App\Entity\Category
```

And if you don't define them, the default entities from the bundle will be used (so `product_entity` will be `Components\Category\Entity\Product`)

So what I want to do it loop through all these entities, and manually map them, simply said, I want to be able to do this:

```
$doctrine->mapEntity(
    $parameterBag->get('product_entity')
);
```

Hope this makes any sense! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create event handler with **loadClassMetadata** doctrine event
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

1. You set mapping inside bundle (e.g. in /Resources/config/doctrine_mapping.yml)
2. You check this configs in your custom handler from all bundles
3. PROFIT

Get bundles:
'kernel.bundles_metadata' parameter in container

Comment: Thank you! The loadClassMetadata event got me going in the right direction!